# How to access secondary inputs with variable names in R Shiny?

Tags: r, loops, user-interface, input, shiny

I'm trying to have the user enter a numeric input, then generate a number of input boxes equal to that first numeric input. I would then like to find the sum of the responses to these secondary numeric inputs. However, I am having trouble accessing these variables in a comprehensive way, since their names are created used numeric variables. Right now when I run it I get this error:
`Warning: Error in get: object 'inp21' not found`

Thanks

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("inp1",
                         "Enter num:",1)
        ),
 
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("more_inp"),
            textOutput("num_inps")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
    
    counter <- reactiveValues(countervalue = 0)
    counter2 <- reactiveValues(counter2value = 0)
    
    output$more_inp <- renderUI({
        
        #Generates number of numeric inputs equal to original numeric input
        mylist <- lapply(1:input$inp1, function(i) {
            
            inp_identifier <- paste("inp2", i, sep="")
            inp_name<- paste("Input2",i,sep=" ")
            
            
            list(
                numericInput(inp_identifier,inp_name, 5)
            )
            
        })
        do.call(tagList, unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE))
    })
    
    #Display number of secondary inputs
    
    #Count number of secondary inputs
    observeEvent(input$inp1, {
        counter$countervalue <- counter$countervalue + 1     
    })
    
    #Find sum of secondary inputs
    output$num_inps<-renderText(input$inp1)
    
            observeEvent(input$inp1,{
                for (i in 1:counter$countervalue) {
                    counter2$counter2value <- counter2$counter2value + get(paste("inp2", i, sep=""))
                    print(counter2$counter2value)
                }
            })
       
}
```

## Run the application

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Try replacing `get(paste("inp2", i, sep=""))` with `input[[paste("inp2", i, sep="")]]`.

Comment: Explanation: if it were pre-defined, you would reference it as `input$inp21` or `input[["inp21"]]`, not `get("inp21")`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! I tried that and now it prints the value of print(counter2$counter2value) as numeric(0). Do you know what's going on here? Thanks

Comment: @r2evans BTW, numeric(0) refers to a numeric vector of length 0.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly to r2evans suggestion simply "filter" out the case when an input field cannot be found. It seems that this `observeEvent` is called before the other input fields can be created. As a consequence, you receive an empty vector (`numeric(0)`) when you try to access one of them.

```
  observeEvent(input$inp1,{
    for (i in 1:counter$countervalue) {
      if (isTruthy(input[[paste0("inp2", i)]])) {
        counter2$counter2value <- counter2$counter2value + input[[paste0("inp2", i)]]
        print(counter2$counter2value)
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking for the presence before adding. The `observeEvent` block is firing aggressively, so even though `counter$countervalue` is 1, there are not additional input fields present, so `input[[paste("inp2", i, sep="")]]` returns `NULL`. Anything plus null is `numeric(0)`.

### How to find this

```r
  observeEvent(input$inp1,{
    browser()
    for (i in 1:counter$countervalue) {
      counter2$counter2value <- counter2$counter2value + get(paste("inp2", i, sep=""))
      print(counter2$counter2value)
    }
  })
```

Run your app. When it hits the debugger and shows you `Browse[2]>`, then

```r
counter$countervalue
# [1] 1
counter2$counter2value
# [1] 0
i <- 1L
get(paste("inp2", i, sep=""))
# Error in get(paste("inp2", i, sep = "")) : object 'inp21' not found
input[[ paste("inp2", i, sep="") ]]
# NULL
names(input)
# [1] "inp1"
```

A quick check could be to look for that `paste(.)` name in `names(input)`.

### Tangent

`for (i in 1:n)` works fine as long as you are 100% certain that `n` here will always be 1 or greater. If there is the remote possibility that it will be `<1`, then the results will be rather unintuitive.

That is, if `n` is 0, then I would expect the `for` loop to do nothing. As a vector example,

```r
for (nm in c('a','b')) ...  # executes twice     GOOD
for (nm in c()) ...         # does not execute   GOOD
for (i in 1:2) ...          # executes twice     GOOD
for (i in 1:0) ...          # executes twice     BAD
```

The reason is that `1:0` resolves to a reverse sequence, so `seq(1, 0)` and therefore `c(1L, 0L)`.

A safer alternative if you expect a possible zero is `seq_len`:

```r
seq_len(2)
# [1] 1 2
seq_len(0)
# integer(0)
```

(`seq(1, length.out=n)` is equivalent.)

An even safer alternative if you cannot guarantee "positive only", then

```r
seq_len(max(0, n))
```

(since `seq_len(-1)` is an error).

### Suggested solution

```r
  observeEvent(input$inp1,{
    for (i in seq_len(counter$countervalue)) {    # or max(0, ...)
      nm <- paste("inp2", i, sep="")
      if (nm %in% names(input)) {
        counter2$counter2value <- counter2$counter2value + input[[nm]]
        print(counter2$counter2value)
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks a lot. It works now. I added in another button to calculate the sums after pressing it. That made things much smoother